# Firefox on Ubuntu doesn't load source-maps from file procotol

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I'm developing a web application that uses bundled JavaScript. In order to debug this code from my local webserver I'm using a source map. The source files are not available to the (Apache) webserver since the bundling process collects them from various places on my computer.

My problem is that Firefox correctly shows the file names and lines in the console when trying to open a source file in the dev tools, however, it yields this error:

```
Error while fetching an original source: can't assign to property "metadata" on "unsupported protocol for sourcemap request file:///var/[ ... ]": not an object
Source URL: <unknown>
```

When I copy the file URL to another browser window it loads normally, I installed Firefox via the tarball, not via snap, so system files can be accessed. In Chrome the source loads fine and debugging works as expected. However, I also need to use the Firefox debugger.

Is there maybe a hidden config option or startup flag that modifies which sources are allowed for sourcemaps? The only alternative I can think of would be to create a virtual host for hosting these resources and create symlinks from there which would be quite annoying.

Edit: This is how my sourcemap looks like

```json
{
    "version": 3,
    "sourceRoot": "",
    "mappings": "AAAA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;[ ... ]",
    "names": [],
    "sources": [
        "file:///var/[ ... ]",
        "file:///var/[ ... ]",
        "file:///var/[ ... ]",
        "file:///var/[ ... ]",
        [ ... ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does the sourcemap look like ?

Comment: @harrymc see the edit to the question above

Answer (score 1):

Firefox prevents http pages from accessing `file://`. You either have to serve the test page from `file://` or set up another apache/another vhost to serve the files from `/var` you want.

see: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/client/shared/source-map-loader/utils/network-request.js

`"http:", "https:", "data:"` are always supported. `"chrome:", "file:", "moz-extension:"` are only available if they match the source of the page.

You can set a `sourceRoot` value to your source map pointing to your special apache/vhost that will serve the files in `/var`.